# Mark data as sensitive in python

Tags: python, security, passwords, coredump

I need to store a user's password for a short period of time in memory. How can I do so yet not have such information accidentally disclosed in coredumps or tracebacks? Is there a way to mark a value as "sensitive", so it's not saved anywhere by a debugger?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728164/securely-erasing-password-in-memory-python

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edit**

I have made a solution that uses ctypes (which in turn uses C) to zero memory.

```
import sys
import ctypes

def zerome(string):
    location = id(string) + 20
    size     = sys.getsizeof(string) - 20

    memset =  ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.memset
    # For Linux, use the following. Change the 6 to whatever it is on your computer.
    # memset =  ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6").memset

    print "Clearing 0x%08x size %i bytes" % (location, size)

    memset(location, 0, size)
```

I make no guarantees of the safety of this code. It is tested to work on x86 and CPython 2.6.2. A longer writeup is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100929111257/http://www.codexon.com/posts/clearing-passwords-in-memory-with-python).

Decrypting and encrypting in Python will not work. Strings and Integers are interned and persistent, which means you are leaving a mess of password information all over the place.

Hashing is the standard answer, though of course the plaintext eventually needs to be processed somewhere.

The correct solution is to do the sensitive processes as a C module.

But if your memory is constantly being compromised, I would rethink your security setup.

Comment: This is right. If you /ever/ read the password into a Python object, there is the potential for it being compromised by a dump.  Even using C isn't perfect (you can still freeze the program and use a kernel-level debugger), but it should be good enough.

Comment: If this is the same `memset` as is mentioned in the following article, this too is unsafe. http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0178/ or https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insecure_Compiler_Optimization

Comment: Danny: memset is safe. The articles you link to are about C compilers removing memset calls. When we call memset explicitly from Python, it is called.

Comment: @Barry Archive.org strikes again! [Here is a backup of the writeup](http://web.archive.org/web/20100929111257/http://www.codexon.com/posts/clearing-passwords-in-memory-with-python)

Comment: This solution crashes Python 2.7.2 (Segmentation fault:11) under Mac OS 10.8.5 (using `memset=ctypes.CDLL("libc.dylib").memset`)

Comment: I have two basic questions for this code -

Why do we need to load the library when we can use ctypes.memset(location, 0, size)? I see the crash in python 2.7.11 with memset = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6").memset memset(location, 0, size)
Is there a limit on the string length passed to this function? I see it works for me for smaller strings, but fails to memset longer strings with 240 bytes or more. Is that expected?

Answer (score 5):

> ... **The only solution to this is to use mutable data structures.** That
>   is, you must only use data structures that allow you to dynamically
>   replace elements. For example, in Python you can use lists to store an
>   array of characters. However, *every time you add or remove an element
>   from a list, the language might copy the entire list behind your back*,
>   depending on the implementation details. To be safe, if you have to
>   dynamically resize a data structure, **you should create a new one, copy
>   data, and then write over the old one**. For example:

```
def paranoid_add_character_to_list(ch, l):
  """Copy l, adding a new character, ch.  Erase l.  Return the result."""
  new_list = []
  for i in range(len(l)):
    new_list.append(0)
  new_list.append(ch)
  for i in range(len(l)):
    new_list[i] = l[i]
    l[i] = 0
  return new_list
```

**Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/s-data.html**

- Author: John Viega (viega@list.org) is co-author of Building Secure
  Software (Addison-Wesley, 2001) and Java Enterprise Architecture
  (O'Reilly and Associates, 2001). John has authored more than 50
  technical publications, primarily in the area of software security.
  He also wrote Mailman, the GNU Mailing List Manager and ITS4, a tool
  for finding security vulnerabilities in C and C++ code.

Comment: As a variant: using this technique to populate a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) results in an object which can be used in place of a `bytes` instance in a lot of python code ... and can be equivalently cleared afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

No way to "mark as sensitive", but you could encrypt the data in memory and decrypt it again when you need to use it -- not a perfect solution but the best I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

- XOR with a one-time pad stored separately
- always store salted hash rather than password itself

or, if you're very paranoid about dumps, store unique random key in some other place, e.g. i a different thread, in a registry, on your server, etc.

Answer (score 1):

based on culix's answer: the following works with Linux 64-bit architecture.
Tested on Debian based systems.

```
import sys 
import ctypes

def erase(var_to_erase):
    strlen = len(var_to_erase)
    offset = sys.getsizeof(var_to_erase) - strlen - 1
    ctypes.memset(id(var_to_erase) + offset, 0, strlen)
    del var_to_erase               # derefrencing the pointer.
```