# How do I modify a single character in a string, in Python?

Tags: python, string

How do I modify a single character in a string, in Python? Something like:

```
 a = "hello"
 a[2] = "m"
```

'str' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change one character in a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python. You can use a list of characters instead:

```
a = list("hello")
```

When you want to display the result use `''.join(a)`:

```
a[2] = 'm'
print ''.join(a)
```

Answer (score 12):

In python, string are immutable. If you want to change a single character, you'll have to use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
a = "hello"
a = a[:2] + "m" + a[3:]
```

Comment: I suppose this would cost more memory if it's a really big string since you have to join three other strings together to form a new string, right?

Comment: Oh, yeah! If you need to do a whole bunch of these type of manipulations, it's best to use a list of characters. Unless you happen to already have a string and just happen to want to change one character. Even then, it's probably faster to create and modify a list.

Comment: @Shane: See @detly's answer below for a simple example.

Answer (score 8):

Try constructing a list from it. When you pass an iterable into a list constructor, it will [turn it into a list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) (this is a bit of an oversimplification, but usually works).

```
a = list("hello")
a[2] = m
```

You can then join it back up with `''.join(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because strings in python are immutable.