# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I have a problem in my python program. In this program, the user enters a string and then the program calls a function to convert from the unicode letter to the closest ASCII symbol (e.g. ş -> s ö -> o etc.) but i get 
`TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Code:

```
__author__ = 'neo'
ceviri = {
    'ş':'s','Ş':'S',
    'ğ':'g','Ğ':'G',
    'ı':'i','İ':'I',
    'ü':'u','Ü':'U',
    'ö':'o','Ö':'O'
}
def karakterDegistir(x):
   p = x[:]
   y = sorted(ceviri.keys())
   u = 0
   while u < len(y):
      if p[u] in y:
         p[u] = ceviri[p[u]]
      u = u + 1
   return p
print(karakterDegistir('şeker'))
```

Comment: Python doesn't allow you to modify a string in place. You need to build a new string with the translations, and return that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I modify a single character in a string, in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861026/how-do-i-modify-a-single-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Barmar's comment about python not allowing you to modify strings in place, you're iterating through your copy of the input array, but you're going up to the length of y (your list of keys), not the length of p.

A much more pythonic way would be 
`return ''.join([ceviri.get(c,c) for c in x])`

(Edit: thanks Dair), and since I'm editing:
To clarify: this goes through each letter in x, and if that letter is in your ceviri dictionary, return the value, otherwise use the original letter.  This creates a list of letters' ''.join combines all the letters into a string.

Comment: Small detail: `return ''.join([ceviri.get(c,c) for c in x])`