# How to randomly capitalize a letter in a string

Tags: python, string

I want to randomly capitalize a letter in a string but it doesn't seem to work.  I think the problem is how i'm accessing and capitalizing a letter, but i don't know any other way.
I've tried using many other answers for this question, but i could not understand their methods (i'm still pretty new) and when i tried implementing it to my code it did not work.

```
import random

def random_cap(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        rn = random.randint(0,1)
        if rn == 1:
            word[i].upper
            rn = random.randint(0,1)
    print(word)
word = input("Type word to randomly capitalize: " )
random_cap(word)
```

Comment: `word[i].upper` does not capitalize the i-th letter in `word`. In fact it does nothing how you have it because  `upper` is a method of a  string, so you have to call it, and assign the result to some variable.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable.  `word[i].upper` just returns as its value the capital version of the i-th letter, but doesn't change the original string.

You need to do something like:

```
word = word[:i] + word[i].upper() + word[i+1:]
```

Alternatively, you could convert word to a list of characters:

```
wl = list(word)
```

Then randomly capitalize some of the letters:

```
if ...:
    wl[i] = wl[i].upper()
```

then put the whole thing back together as a word:

```
word = ''.join(wl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import random

def random_cap(word):
    wordList = list(word)
    for i in range(wordList.__len__()):
        rn = random.randint(0, 1)
        if rn == 1:
            wordList[i] = wordList[i].upper()
            rn = random.randint(0, 1)
    print(''.join(wordList))
word = input("Type word to randomly capitalize: " )
random_cap(word)
```

Output:

```
Type word to randomly capitalize: I am so happy right now!
I Am sO HAPpY RIGHt nOw!
```

Just like Frank Yellin's code but it is based on your provided code.

Also, this could be marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861026/how-do-i-modify-a-single-character-in-a-string-in-python) and/or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942497/randomly-capitalize-letters-in-string).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
import random

def randomize(input):
    out = str()

    for i in input:
        rn = random.randint(0, 1)
        if rn == 1:
            out += str(i.upper())
        else:
            out += str(i)

    print(out)

randomize('teststring')
```