# Delete a repeated character from only one specific position and not from all places of the string in python

Tags: python, string, replace, character

Say there is a specific string : `bacdefaxyza`.

Now the character `a` is repeated 3 times. I now want to be able to delete or replace with `""` only the `a` in the middle but not all. Is there a way to do so? i.e. : I need to be able to delete that `a` from any place I wish ( index of that character is known ). Is it possible?

I tried using the `replace()` function but it deletes only the first occurrence, or more, but not at a particular index/place that I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883980/find-the-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-a-string

Comment: what does only the "a in the middle but not all " mean ?

Comment: are there always the same number of `a`'s?

Comment: `result = string[:index] + string[index+1:]`

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-letter-in-string-by-index

Comment: @praneeth I meant to say that, I want to remove that `a` in the middle (the second one) but keep the rest.

Comment: @SirParselot yup...thanks for the link! I also got the same answer here anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the index is known:

```
s = 'bacdefaxyza'
idx = 6
s[:idx]+s[idx+1:]
```

Comment: I think OP means for a general string.

Comment: I don't know how OP is finding the index, so I just hard-coded `idx = 6`, but they did say that the index is known.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks! I think that should do it!!

Answer (score 0):

coming to your example,
lets assign the string to a variable say s

Use the python interactive shell to test this out

```
>>>s = 'bacdefaxyza'
```

lets assign the result to a new variable called k where we are going to replace second 'a' character with empty character ''

```
>>>k = s[:6]+s[6:].replace('a','')

>>>print(k)
bacdefxyz
```