# How to remove a middle character from string by strip in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want remove the "+" sign from the input 'x+y' where x and y is an string(single digit) and print the result.

For example, I am entering 5+7 and it should display 57

Here is the code:

```
opr = input("Enter string").strip("+")
print(opr)
```

This code is not removing the "+" sign.

Comment: `str.strip` removes leading and trailing characters only

Comment: try opr.replace('+','')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use replace

```
opr = input("Enter string").replace("+","")
print(opr)
```

Comment: @Aziz: `strip` does not remove characters in the middle of a string.

Comment: `>>> help(str.strip)`

Help on method_descriptor:

strip(...)
    S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode

    Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

Answer (score 1):

If your read the FineManual(tm), you'll find out that `str.strip()` only removes from the start and end of the string.

The solution here is of course to use `str.replace("+", "")`

Comment: Thanks! for the help!