# Python text replace is not working. random number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
        letters = ['h', 'i', 'r', 'l', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'n', 't', 's']
        text = "A novel is a relatively long work of narrative fiction, normally written in prose form, and which is typically published as a book".lower()
        for j in text:
            if not(j in letters):
                text.replace(j, '')
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I want to replace letter to '' in the text if it is not in my array letters
but it it is not working

Comment: replace method return new string it doesnt update old string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: can you provide expected output for smaller string?

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable objects in python. So, here 
`text.replace(j, '')` only returns you a string with replaced/deleted character, but does not change the original.

Answer (score 1):

As [Vorashil Farzaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62025530/7303434) well said, strings are immutable objects, which basically means that you cannot edit them after they are created. The `replace()` function doesn't change the string in place, but it returns a new string with the replacement that you want.

Another way of getting the desired output, might be by using the `join()` function of the `str` class, passing a generator comprehension to it, with filtering purposes. This will give you a new string, which you could re-assign to the `text` name, if you want.

```
letters = ['h', 'i', 'r', 'l', 'o', 'e', 'a', 'n', 't', 's', ' ']
text = "A novel is a relatively long work of narrative fiction, normally written in prose form, and which is typically published as a book".lower()
text = "".join(letter for letter in text if letter in letters)
print(text)
# outputs: a noel is a relatiel lon or o narratie ition norall ritten in rose or an hih is tiall lishe as a oo
```

Please note that in order of getting that output, you need to include the space character (`' '`) within the `letters` list. Otherwise, you'd get all letters joined together.