# Deleting words in the list of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to delete words in phrases.

For example, I have this paragraph:

```
Do you know what would be amazingly awesome? BOS-FLL PLEASE!!!!!!! I want to fly with only you.

 I love this graphic.

 amazing customer service, again!  <3  <3  RaeAnn in SF - she's the best! #customerservice 
 Love the team running Gate E9 at LAS tonight. Waited for a delayed flight, and they kept things entertaining

 you have the absolute best team and customer service ever.  Every time I fly with you I'm delighted.  Thank you!
```

I got 4 phrases in a list, and I want to delete every term like "the"

I tried like it :

```
for i in tweets_dev:
    i.replace("the"," ")
    print(i)
```

but it didn't works!

I got always "the" on my list. Please guide me on what is the main error, and how I can perform above mention task. Thanks in advance.

thanks for reading

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Try
`tweets_dev.lower().replace(' the ', ' ')`

Output:

````
 i love this graphic.

 amazing customer  service, again!  <3  <3  raeann in sf - she's best! #customerservice
 love team running gate e9 at las tonight. waited for a delayed flight, and they kept things entertaining

 you have absolute best team and customer service ever.  every time i fly with you i'm delighted.  thank you!```
````

Comment: `replace` isn't in-place, you need to assign the return value to something. Also be careful for word boundaries and casing (I don't know what OP wants here but this will do `"thesaurus"` -> `" saurus"`).

Comment: I've edited the answer so it respects word boundaries and casing.

Comment: Spaces aren't the same as word boundaries. It now fails on "`The boy"`. I'd ask OP for clarification before making these assumptions, and we still have an assignment problem--`replace` doesn't mutate the argument object.

Comment: As far as I could tell, he would want ` The boy` to be replaced, but if he could elaborate further that'd help people answer his question.