# How can i replace one character in a string

Tags: python, methods

I have been asked the change the "d" into "e" except the first d.
Here is the string
"ddar astronaut. pldase, stop drasing md!"
which method do i have to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723751/replacing-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

You can find the first occurrence of `d` with `s.find('d')+1` and use that as an index to split the string into 2 parts. Use `str.replace` on the second part.

```
s = "ddar astronaut. pldase, stop drasing md!"

idx = s.find('d')+1
s[:idx]+s[idx:].replace('d','e')
```

```
'dear astronaut. please, stop erasing me!'
```

Comment: thanks! so the replace method is only replacing the d after the idx?

Comment: since you dont want to modify the string until the first occurance of `d`, the replace is only for the latter part. Try changing the sentence and printing `s[:idx]` and `s[idx:].replace('d','e')` separately to see whats happening