# Python - use lists instead of strings?

Tags: python

[From an S.O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python):

"Don't modify strings.

Work with them as lists; turn them into strings only when needed.

... code sample ...

Python strings are immutable (i.e. they can't be modified). There are a lot of reasons for this. Use lists until you have no choice, only then turn them into strings."

Is this considered best practice?

I find it a bit odd that Python has methods that return new modified strings (such as upper(), title(), replace() etc.) but doesn't have an insert method that returns a new string. Have I missed such a method?

Edit: I'm trying to rename files by inserting a character:

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    i.insert(3, '_')
```

Which doesn't work due to immutability. Adding to the beginning of a string works fine though:

```
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    os.rename(i, 'some_random_string' + i)
```

Edit2: the solution:

```
>>> for i in os.listdir('.'):                                                │··
...  os.rename(i, i[:4] + '_' + i[4:])
```

Slicing certainly is nice and solves my problem, but is there a logical explanation why there is no insert() method that returns a new string?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, there is no `insert` method, but you can easily do that and more than that with available methods. Is your question about insertion or about best practices? It doesn't feel specific enough. If you have a specific problem (and maybe a solution you are not sure about), why not post it here?

Comment: Hi. I'm attempting to learn Python (again). I'm setting silly challenges for myself. This one is to rename FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 to FILE_1 FILE_2 FILE_3. Thanks.

Comment: If you know both formats in advance, you don't need to convert one to the other at all: `for i in range(1, 4): os.rename('FILE' + str(i), 'FILE_' + str(i))`.

Comment: Thanks Lev. What if you just wanted to insert an underscore (or other character) at a particular position for every item in your loop?

Comment: `data[:4] + '_' + data[4:]`

Comment: Yep, just use slices. And in more complex cases, `str.replace`, `str.format` or `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks very much! Never occurred to me. I still think insert() would be easier though...

Comment: If you REALLY want to use a function, you can create your own function to do so... It's going to use slices as well, though:
http://ideone.com/P6WZLo

Comment: `import this` : "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", "Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert at a particular spot, you can use slices and +. For example:

```
a = "hello"
b = a[:2] + '_S1M0N_' + a[2:]
```

then b will be equal to he_S1M0N_llo.

Answer (score 2):

It's at least arguably a best practice *if you are doing a very large number of modifications to a string*. It is *not* a general purpose best practice. It's simply a useful technique for solving performance problems when doing heavy string manipulation.

My advice is, don't do it until performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a generic function that works on any sequence (strings, lists, tuples, etc.) using the [slice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) syntax:

```
def insert(s, c, p):
    return s[:p] + c + s[p:]

insert('FILE1', '_', 4)
> 'FILE_1'
```

Comment: That's useful. So useful I wonder why it isn't already in Python...!