# Convert some C function to Python

Tags: python, c, linux, encryption

i need to convert this function in C to Python:

```
void myencrypt(char password[],int mkey)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(password);++i)
    {
    password[i] = password[i] - mkey;
    }
}
```

I try this, but fails...

```
def myencrypt(password, mkey):

    i = 0
    newpass = []

    for i in range(len(password)):
        newpass[i] = ord(password[i]) - mkey;

    return newpass
```

any help ?

Comment: you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: use append. but why convert from c to python in the first palce?. just keep your c code and use cython to wrap

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `chr` to convert the numbers back to characters? (In C, that isn't necessary, because `'a'` and `97` are the same value. But in Python, just as you need `ord` to turn one into the other, you need `chr` to go the other way.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can only assign to an index in a list if the list is long enough, otherwise you will get an IndexError.  Try the following:

```py
def myencrypt(password, mkey):
    i = 0
    newpass = []
    for i in range(len(password)):
        newpass.append(ord(password[i]) - mkey)
    return newpass
```

By using `newpass.append()`, you will just add each new element to the end of the list.  As a side note, you can iterate directly over the elements of `password` which is a bit more concise:

```py
def myencrypt(password, mkey):
    newpass = []
    for x in password:
        newpass.append(ord(x) - mkey)
    return newpass
```

Comment: While you're improving the OP's code, get rid of the unnecessary `i = 0`, and maybe explain about the missing `chr`, and it might be worth showing the list comprehension equivalent, which turns 4 lines into 1.

Answer (score 2):

The C code is modifying `password` in-place. So, the closest equivalent would be:

```
def myencrypt(password, mkey):
    for i in range(len(password)):
        password[i] = chr(ord(password[i]) - mkey)
```

That assumes `password` is a `list` of characters, rather than a string.

Also, notice that I'm calling `chr` on the result of each `ord(password[i]) - mkey`, because otherwise you're replacing each character with a number—for example, `myencrypt(['a'], 32)` would give you `[65]` instead of `['A']`. (This isn't necessary in C, because `65` and `'A'` are the same value in C.)

You're more likely going to want to call this function with a string, and get back a string. You *can* still use the C-style in-place functionality to do it, just by converting and converting back:

```
def myencrypt(password, mkey):
    newpass = list(password)
    for i in range(len(newpass)):
        newpass[i] = chr(ord(newpass[i]) - mkey)
    return ''.join(newpass)
```

However, this isn't a very Pythonic way to do things. A more idiomatic solution would be:

```
def myencrypt(password, mkey):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(ch) - mkey) for ch in password)
```

And that brings up a more general point: Except in very trivial cases, trying to "convert C code to Python" directly is a bad idea. Instead, figure out what the C code does, and write new Python code that accomplishes the same task in the best way for Python, rather than in the way the C code did it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't use the word "encrypt" in this function. In modern Python you can use a `bytearray` object, that is mutable. Then convert to string.

```
def myobfuscate(password, mkey):
    a = bytearray(password)
    for i, c in enumerate(password):
        a[i] = ord(c) - mkey
    return str(a)


myobfuscate("secret", 10)
# OUT: 'i[Yh[j'
```

In Python, strings are immutable, they can't be alterend in-place. So you would use a function like this as:

```
pw = myobfuscate(pw, 10)
```

Assuming you won't need the original value any more. This replaces the original reference with a new object that the function returns.

Comment: Or `return ''.join(chr(ord(c) - mkey) for c in password)`.

Comment: The elements of a `bytearray` are integers, not characters, so that should be `a[i] -= mkey` (or, if you prefer, `a[i] = ord(c) - mkey`). (In 2.7, the `chr` is harmless, even though the documentation says otherwise; in 3.x, it will raise an exception.)

Comment: @Jon-Eric: That's really a completely different answer from Keith's. It might be useful as a comment on F.J's answer, because it _is_ equivalent to (and shorter, and probably more Python than) his.

Comment: @abarnert Fair enough.

Comment: @Jon-Eric Yes, but for those new to Python I try to make the example a little more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you folks for all answers, but i use a hex key like this:
 print myencrypt("mything",0xFABBCA09333)
The solutions posted help me allot but have error when i use a hex key