# how to change a character by its position in a string python

Tags: python, string, position, numeric

Im trying to make a Hangman game and I need to change certain characters in a string.
Eg: '-----', I want to change the third dash in this string, with a letter. This would need to work with a word of any length, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See: [change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @j.f. is correct. Strings cannot be changed in Python, unlike Java or C. You should convert the string to a list, and then you can modify that list character by character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable, make it a list and then replace the character, then turn it back to a string like so:

```
s = '-----'
s = list(s)
s[2] = 'a'
s = ''.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String = list(String)
String[0] = "x"
String  = str(String)
```

Will also work. I am not sure which one (the one with .join and the one without) is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using slicing ,

```
>>> a
'this is really string'
>>> a[:2]+'X'+a[3:]
'thXs is really string'
>>>
```