# Python Replace Character In List

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a Python list that looks like the below:

```
list = ['|wwwwwwwwadawwwwwwwwi', '|oooooooocFcooooooooi']
```

I access the letter in the index I want by doing this:

```
list[y][x]
```

For example, `list[1][10]` returns `F`.

I would like to replace `F` with a value. Thus changing the string in the list.

I have tried `list[y][x] = 'o'` but it throws the error:

```
    self.map[y][x] = 'o'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Python strings are immutable, and it can be done in this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change one character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

As @Marcin says, Python strings are immutable.  If you have a specific character/substring you want to replace, there is [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string.replace#string.replace).  You can also use lists of characters instead of strings, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python) if you want to support the functionality of changing one particular character.

If you want something like `string.replace`, but for an index rather than a substring, you can do something like:

```
def replaceOneCharInString(string, index, newString):
    return string[:index] + newString + string[index+len(newString):]
```

You would need to do some length checking, though.

Edit: forgot `string` before the brackets on `string[index+len(newString):]`.  Woops.

Answer (score 2):

Since python strings are immutable, they cannot be modified. You need to make new ones. One way is as follows:

```
tmp_list = list(a_list[1])
tmp_list[10] = 'o' # simulates: list[1][10]='o'
new_str = ''.join(tmp_list)
#Gives |oooooooococooooooooi
# substitute the string in your list
a_list[1] = new_str
```

Answer (score 0):

As marcin says, strings are immutable in Python so you can not assign to individual characters in an existing string. The reason you can index them is that thay *are* sequences. Thus

```
for c in "ABCDEF":
    print(c)
```

Will work, and print each character of the string on a separate line.

To achieve what you want you need to build a new string.For example, here is a brute force approach to replacing a single character of a string

```
def replace_1(s, index, c)
    return s[:index] + c + s[index+1:]
```

Which you can use thus:

```
self.map[y] = replace_1(self.map[y], x, 'o')
```

This will work because `self.map` is list, which is mutable by design.

Answer (score 0):

Let use L to represent the "list" since list is a function in python

```
L= ['|wwwwwwwwadawwwwwwwwi', '|oooooooocFcooooooooi']
L[1]='|oooooooococooooooooi'
print(L)
```

Unfortunately changing a character from an **object** (in this case) is not supported. The proper way would be to remove the object and add a new string object.

Output

```
['|wwwwwwwwadawwwwwwwwi', '|oooooooococooooooooi']
```