# Python string recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

I have to recursively replace characters in a string with new characters. I'm a bit stuck right now, however. I cannot import anything, so here is my code:

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use any built in functions besides len() and index/splice operators. This means I can't use 'in'. This is a homework question, but I don't expect you guys to solve it for me, just to point out why my code isn't working. Thanks!

```
def replace_char(astr, old_char, new_char):
    newstr = ""
    if astr == "":
        return newstr
    elif astr[0] == old_char:
        newstr += new_char
        return replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char)
    else:
        newstr += astr[0]
        return replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char)
```

Any ideas on why it isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: you make newstring empty everytime you call it ... but then you try to add to it ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change one character in a string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
def replace_char(astr, old_char, new_char):
    if astr == "":
        return astr
    elif astr[0] == old_char:
        return new_char + replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char)
    else:
        return astr[0] + replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char)
```

The only string you ever returned in your old code was an empty one:

```
newstr = ""
    if astr == "":
        return newstr
```

You need to be adding characters to your return value as you recurse through the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_char(s, old, new):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ''
    elif len(s) == 1:
        if s == old:
            return new
        else:
            return s
    else:
        return replace_char(s[0], old, new) + replace_char(s[1:], old, new)

>>> replace_char('test', 't', 'c')
'cesc'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joran Beasley is right -- you recreate `newstr` each time you go through the function. Change the function header to include newstr:

`def replace_char(astr, old_char, new_char, newstr = '')`

And change all the calls to the function as well:

`return replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char, newstr)`

Here's the full code:

```
def replace_char(astr, old_char, new_char, newstr = ''):
    newstr = ""
    if astr == "":
        return newstr
    elif astr[0] == old_char:
        newstr += new_char
        return replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char, newstr)
    else:
        newstr += astr[0]
        return replace_char(astr[1:], old_char, new_char, newstr)
```

This implementation keeps most of your existing code in place, but it would make far more sense to use `astr.replace(old_char, new_char)` in most situations

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_chr(a_string,old,new):
    if not a_string:return a_string
    next_char = a_string[0] if a_string[0] != old else new
    return next_char + replace_chr(a_string[1:],old,new)
```