# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my WIP Python hangman game?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import random

words = ["antelope", "attacking", "architect", "defector", "mindless", "trauma", "immunity", 
    "fairytale", "approaching", "cuteness", "identical", "caterpillar"]

lives = 6
word = random.choice(words)
guessedWord = False

print "Welcome to Hangman. You have 6 lives, good luck!"
hiddenWord = "_ " * len(word)
print hiddenWord

while True:
    if lives == 0 and not guessedWord == True:
        break

    guess = raw_input("Guess A Letter: ")

    if len(guess) > 1:
        print "Please only guess letters."
    else:
        if guess.isdigit() == True:
        print "Please only guess letters."
        else:
            for letter in word:
                if guess == letter:
                    hiddenWord[letter] == letter
                    print "Nice, You got a letter!"
                    print hiddenWord
                else:
                    "That letter is not in this word. -1 life."
                    lives = lives - 1
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\Brian Gunsel\Desktop\Code\Python\hangman.py", line 28, in <module>
    hiddenWord[letter] == letter
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

And it just isn't working properly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that letter is a string, and hiddenWord is expecting an integer index. To fix this, you want to use the index of that letter when modifying hiddenWord. An easy way to do this is with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for i, letter in enumerate(word):
    if guess == letter:
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord[:i] + letter + hiddenWord[i+1:]
        print "Nice, You got a letter!"
        print hiddenWord
    else:
        "That letter is not in this word. -1 life."
        lives = lives - 1
```

Comment: This won't work exactly as-is because strings are immutable in Python; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: @Mike I realized right after I pushed submit. Fixed now.