# Python join method returning a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of elements ("tokens") that I assume are acting like strings. I want to find words with an underscore in them and replace the underscore with a space. I have the following code:

```
for e in tokens:
      if '_' in e:
            cmpd = list(e)
            cmpd[e.find('_')] = ' '
            ''.join(cmpd)
            new_tokens[index] = cmpd
```

It's basically identical to what's here:
[Change one character in a string in Python?](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python/)

Later I'm trying to concatenate all the list elements in a sentence, each separated by a space, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

And if I print out `e` and `cmpd`, I get this output:

```
e: my_string

cmpd: ['m', 'y', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Why is cmpd a list and not a string?

Comment: You want to replace the underscores? Or the entire word?

Comment: Perhaps you can do `string.replace('_', ' ')`

Comment: `join()` is not inline. you need to assign it to something

Comment: Just the underscores

Comment: Can you include output of `print(tokens)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign `''.join(cmpd)` to `cmpd` using `=`.:

```
cmpd=''.join(cmpd)
```

Comment: So obvious I completely missed it... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join(cmpd)
```

This line converts `cmpd` to a string, then throws that string away. You should keep the string:

```
cmpd = ''.join(cmpd)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems here:

- you use an `index` that is not defined,
- `.join` does **not** work inplace;
- if a token contains multiple underscores only one will be replaced;
- if a token does not contain an underscore, it is not added; and
- ...

What about:

```
new_tokens = [token.replace('_',' ') for token in tokens]
```

This replaces the entire loop and makes it very clear that you are replacing underscores with spaces.

Comment: The replace function is good to know, thanks for that! I don't have any words with more than one underscore, so I wasn't too bothered with finding multiple underscores. In this case, I suppose I could write `cmpd = e.replace('_',' ')` which is certainly neater! The for loop is necessary though, as I have multiple clauses for different cases.

Comment: @eihe: yeah in case the loop is more complex, you can indeed write `cmpd = ...`. If it is however a simple problem list comprehension is the way to go since it is faster and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
no_underscores = [x.replace('_', ' ') for x in tokens]
print(' '.join(no_underscores))
```

So what happens is that you create a new list (you can also overwrite the previous one) that contains the elements of the old one but without the underscores (`.replace` works even if the string you are looking for is not there). On the second line all elements of the new list are `join`ed together with a space in between them.

If you feel comfortable with the above, you can even combine them like so:

```
print(' '.join(x.replace('_', ' ') for x in tokens))
```

which has the advantage of not creating any extra lists.

Comment: Here you join with a space?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "*concatenate all the list elements in a sentence, each separated by a space*". Am I reading\interpreting that wrong?

Comment: ah the join is on the tokens, not the characters. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

when you get to this line `cmpd = list(e)` e is a string and you are converting it to a list this will make each character an item in a list