# Replacing a character within a string?

Tags: python, character

What is wrong with the following Python code for replacing "." with "-"

```
x = 'BRK.B'
if "." in x
    spot = x.find('.')
    x(spot)="-"
```

Comment: shouldn't that be x[spot] !! and not x(spot)!!!

Comment: and if you want to replace.. use x.replace(".","-")

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran doesn't really make a difference as Python strings are immutable. Either way doesn't work. Both result in a `TypeError`

Comment: thats true, that is why added the next comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos, that makes your code unworkable.

Even if you fix this, `x` is a string, and string is not mutable.

You can just use `str.replace`.

```
 x = x.replace('.','-')
```

Comment: and this is supposed to be a comment!

Comment: People often write the shortest answer that satisfies the OPs question, and then elaborate consistently. May be you people don't like that.

Comment: not really! And this is anyway a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Really? How did it just "ask for more information or suggest improvements"? To me it looks like it was a (partial) answer, and we're explicitly told to "Avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with submitting a partial answer that you then add more detail to, but the initial answer _must_ be an adequate answer in its own right.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
>>> 'BRK.B'.replace('.', '-')
'BRK-B'
```

If you only want to replace the first occurence :

```
>>> 'BRK.B'.replace('.', '-', 1)
'BRK-B'
```

If for some reason, you really want to do it yourself :

```
x = 'BRK.B'
if "." in x: # <- Don't forget : after x
    spot = x.find('.')
    # You're not allowed to modify x, but you can create a new string
    x = x[:spot] + '-' + x[spot+1:]
print(x)
# 'BRK-B'
```