# Python Mac Address Convert Format from : to -

Tags: python, macos

i have a .txt file containing mac address with this format f2:e0:e2:e8:3a:5e

how can i convert f2:e0:e2:e8:3a:5e to f2-e0-e2-e8-3a-5e using pyhton and use it as variable?

Comment: just replace every `:` with a `-`

Comment: @RoadRunner Nope, this works - as my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457318/python-mac-address-convert-format-from-to/53457354#53457354) *should* show - better(faster) than only by replacing - of course replacing works just fine, but if you have to apply this to many addresses(let's say he stores thousands of them in files) then this makes a difference. Worth noting that I also don't need a function call ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open it with `open()`, read contents to a string with the `.read()` method and replace colons with hyphens with the `.replace()` string method. Store the result in a variable.

```
mac_addr = open('your_file.txt').read().replace(':', '-')
```

Comment: Nice. I would also `close()` the file afterwards, or use a `with` context manager.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes, you could but the file object is now detached from any variable, so we can't throw an error on it and since Python will close the file eventually, I'm happy to leave it. :)

Comment: tested this code and it work great. thank your time @JoeIddon

Answer (score 2):

*Probably(from the idea/complexity)* a little faster than Joe's answer(depends on implementation) :

If you can ensure that your address is always in the format `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [...]`

```
with open('your_file.txt') as file:
    address=list(file.read())
    for i in range(2, len(address), 2):
        address[i]="-"
    address="".join(address)
    # do stuff with address here
```

using `with` as proposed by RoadRunner.
And if you want it blazing fast, look at this : 
[Fast character replacing in Python's immutable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22149018/7185318)

This solution will replace every 2nd character with a hyphen.

Comment: `len(address)`? you can't get the length of raw file objects. Same goes for indexing `address[i]="-"`.

Comment: @RoadRunner Oh, sorry, forgot read. Thanks.

Comment: This still won't work. `address[i]="-"` will throw TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment. Are you sure that this will end up being faster than `adress = address.replace(':', '-')`?

Comment: @RoadRunner not anymore ;)

Comment: thank you @LMD i will try this one also..