# how to choose a random position on a list, flip the bit, then go through the next items

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to choose a position of an item in a list and then flip the bit for example

```
pop = ['1010101', '1000101','1001001','1010101,'110001']
```

then randomly choose a position in each set of item in the list and flip the bit to 0 to 1 or 1 to 0

so for example, it will go through each item in a list and choose random position in each item, 1010101 will turn into 1000101, second item will turn into 1000101, 1011001, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

random.seed(42)


def flip(s):
    pos = random.choice(range(len(s)))

    r = list(s)
    r[pos] = '1' if r[pos] == '0' else '0'

    return ''.join(r)


pop = ['1010101', '1000101', '1001001', '1010101', '110001']

result = [flip(s) for s in pop]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['1010111', '0000101', '0001001', '1010111', '111001']
```

Everything is done inside the `flip` function in 3 main steps.

Choose the random position: `pos = random.choice(range(len(s)))`.

Change the bit of the position.

```
r = list(s)
r[pos] = '1' if r[pos] == '0' else '0'
```

And finally return a new string by [joining](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the elements of `r`, `return ''.join(r)`.

**Further**

1. [Change one character in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string)
2. [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)