# How to capitalize certain index of a string in a list?

Tags: python, capitalization, capitalize

I have a list containing multiple stings. 
The strings all start with a "*" and then a "[" with a space in between. Like this:

```
* [context......
```

Now i would like to capitalize "c". 
In other words, i would like to capitalize the first letter of all the strings. But since i use symbols first. the Capitalize() function wont work.

What i have tried is to capitalize the index like this:

```
list = [i[3].capitalize() for i in list]
```

The output of this, is just the capitalized letters. And not the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all start that way, then I think this would do what you want.

`list_ = [i[:3] + i[3:].capitalize() for i in list_]`

Note that you shouldn't use the built in keyword `list` as a variable name (it covers over its purpose in the code).

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I dont use list as a variable name, just changed it for demonstration :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `.title()` which ignores non-alphabetical characters:

```
>>> my_list = ['* [foo]', '* [bar]']
>>> map(lambda s: s.title(), my_list)
['* [Foo]', '* [Bar]']
```

or using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [s.title() for s in my_list]
['* [Foo]', '* [Bar]']
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY:-

```
list1 = [ "* [context......", "* [context1......" ]

for x in list1:

    print(x[:3] + x[3].capitalize() + x[4:])
```

OUTPUT:-

```
* [Context......
* [Context1......
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `upper()` instead of capitalize. Reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string)

```py
test = ['* [context......', '* [bontext......', '* [zontext......']

test = [i[:3] + i[3:4].upper() + i[4:] for i in test]
```