# Replacing a character the first time it occurs in a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace the first equals sign in each line with a comma, and leave the second occurrence of an equals sign alone.

I have attempted a for loop in which I find the index of the character and replace it with a comma, but I cannot select the correct equals sign or replace it.

```
lines = ['Temp = 65   ;   Temperature = degrees Fahrenheit',
     'Mass = 15   ;   Mass = kilograms '
     ]



for line in lines:
    i = line.index('=')
    line.replace('i[1]' , ',')
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python and you cannot modify a character at a given position the way you seems to be trying.

Comment: `'i[1]'` is literal. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there anyway since an int is not subscriptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing one character in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the number of matches to be replaced with a `maxreplace` parameter of 1:

```
line = line.replace('=', ',', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace just the first occurrence with the [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) `count` parameter set to 1.

As well, you cannot modify a string in-place. So the easiest alternative is to use a list comprehension.

```
lines = [
    'Temp = 65   ;   Temperature = degrees Fahrenheit',
    'Mass = 15   ;   Mass = kilograms '
    ]

lines = [s.replace('=', ',', 1) for s in lines]
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['Temp , 65   ;   Temperature = degrees Fahrenheit', 'Mass , 15   ;   Mass = kilograms ']
```