# How to replace variable in string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list called `x` below and I want to replace the ">" (in `x[0][0]`) with the integer 1.

`x = [">000#","#0#00","00#0#"]`

I tried `x[0][0] = 1` but it gives me an error.

Also, can I make `x[0][2]` to become an integer such that 
`x[0][2] += 1` becomes this:
`x = ["1010#","#0#00","00#0#"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one character in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: no i want to know if it can make each individual variable an integer to do addition

Comment: You probably want to consider converting each of those strings into a list then.

Comment: okay im going to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 x[0]=x[0].replace(">","1")
```

Strings are immutable so cant be changed like list.

Or you can convert to list.

```
x[0]=list(x[0])
x[0][0]="1"
x[0][2]=str(int(x[0][2])+1)
x[0]="".join(x[0])
```

Comment: but i cant edit individual variable? for example,  i want to do this: ```x[0][2] += 1``` such that it becomes this: ```x = ["1010#","#0#00","00#0#"]```

Comment: @SomeRandomPersonD check edit

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable; you cannot change their contents. Instead, you need to make a new string out of the old one and assign that to `x[0]`:

```
x = [">000#","#0#00","00#0#"]
# change the first character to a '1'
x[0] = '1' + x[0][1:]
# add 1 to the third character
x[0] = x[0][:2] + str(int(x[0][2]) + 1) + x[0][3:]
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['1010#', '#0#00', '00#0#']
```

Comment: SomeRandomPersonD Please see my edit, it also addresses the second part of your question