# How to replace a character by index in a string containing same characters

Tags: python, string

I'm a newbie in Python and from yesterday, I got stuck to a problem. I tried to reduce it to a few lines, basically, the string is not updating.

```
e = '*****'
for i in e:
    if e.index(i) == 2:
        e = e.replace(i, 'P')
print(e)
# *****
```

Comment: `e.index(i)` will never equal 2 here. It will always find the first `*`

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get in variables inside `for` and `if`- and maybe you will see why it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW: `index(i)` finds first element but you can use `index(i, start_position)` to search next elements.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? I recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one character in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

`index(i)` here is always equal to zero, since the index function finds the index of the first occurence ,ie, here its zero. So index is never 2 and the string is the same.
So to do that, lets use the join function:

```
''.join(e[i] if i!=2 else 'P' for i in range(len(e)))
```

gives:

```
'**P**'
```

Or as @furas says, slice:

```
e[:2] + 'P' + e[3:]
```

Comment: I've tried with random characters ( instead of '*' ) and it worked properly, this is why I got confused...

Comment: @Gabriel i've added a solution for you

Comment: yes, I just tried it, many thanks, this was what I was lookimg for!

Comment: @Gabriel dont forget to tick the answer. :) welcome to SO

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that `e.index(i)` will return the first instance of that character type found, in this case, your entire string is `'\*'` characters, so `e.index('\*')` will always return 0: And your if statement never evaluates to True.

I would suggest the following code to accomplish the desired task:

```
e = '*****'
for index, character in enumerate(e):
    if index == 2:
        e = e[:index] + 'P' + e[index+1:]
print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep your code in its similar format and still solve the problem you can do this:

```
e = "*****"
new_str = ""
for i, j in enumerate(e):
    if i == 2:
        j = "P"
    new_str += j
print(new_str)
```

This will also do it:

```
e = "*****"
e = e[:2] + "P" + e[3:]
print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

So, `replace()` does not take an index. It finds a substring and replaces it with another one. To replace the character at index `1` with character `'X'` you could do:

```
e = '*****'
e = e[:1] + 'X' + e[2:]  # '*X****'
```

Comment: the slicing approach here is the best. replace could work tho, but just not a great option for this one as they all are the same elements within the string and it's not mutable so would have to create a new string. still need to specify an index to locate and then replace

Comment: i has to be `e[:2]  + 'P' + e[3:]`

Comment: oh of course, thanks. I typed too quickly :facepalm:, it's been corrected

Comment: i'll add that too @furas

Comment: it's working fine, I will try to use it in my code, many thanks, very helpful!