# Use integer operator on string from index

Tags: python

In this code here

```
x = '123'
```

How can I addition let's say 5 to the second index. So x would be `'173'`.

Comment: what will be the result of `'123'` and `9` for example?

Comment: That would `'1113'`

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22149018

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I thought I was the only person that had this question, I guess it has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = '123'
n = 5

result = x[:1] + str(int(x[1]) + n) + x[2:]
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
173
```

---

For `n=9`:

```
1113
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into a list, try to turn them into ints or floats, and do your math.

```
x = "123"
x = list(x)

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    try:
        x[i] = int(x[i])
    except:
        x[i] = x[i]

x[1] += 5
print(x)
```

It returns [1.0, 7.0, 3.0].

Comment: Why floats instead of ints?

Comment: @wjandrea oh. I was trying to prevent errors, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into a list, modify the element at the desired index, then join the list back into a string.

```
x = '123'
i = 1
n = 5

y = list(x)
y[i] = str(int(y[i]) + n)
print(''.join(y))  # -> 173
```

*Based on [scvalex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228597/4518341) on [Changing one character in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1228299/4518341)*