# How do I replace a string at a index in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

So I already know how to remove a index like this:

```
i = "hello!"
i= i[:0] + i[1:]

print(i)
'ello!'
```

But how do I replace it?
So maybe I wanted to now put a H where the old h was but if I do this:
`i[0] ="H"`
I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in 
i[0] ="H"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string)

Comment: try doing `i[0] += "H"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without creating a list you could also do:

```py
i = "hello!"
i = "H" + i[1:]
```

More general:

```py
def change_letter(string, letter, index):  # note string is actually a bad name for a variable
    return string[:index] + letter + string[index+1:]

s = "hello!"
s_new = change_letter(s, "H", 0)
print(s_new)
# should print "Hello!"
```

Also note there is a built in function `.capitalize()`

Comment: could I also do this instead of making a new variable:

`s = change_letter(s,"H",0)`
??

Comment: Of course you could. In which variable you store the returned value doesn't matter!

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python, so you can't assign like `i[0] = 'H'`. What you can do is convert the string to list, which is mutable, then you can assign new values at a certain index.

```py
i = "hello!"
i_list = list(i)

i_list[0] = 'H'

i_new = ''.join(i_list)

print(i_new)
```

```
Hello!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string)

As said there you have to make a list out of your string and change the char by selecting an item from that list and reassigning a new value and then in a loop rebuilding the string.

```
>>> s = list("Hello zorld")
>>> s
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'z', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> s[6] = 'W'
>>> s
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> "".join(s)
'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = "hello!"
print(i)  ## will print hello!
i = "H" + i[1:]
print(i) ## will print Hello!
```