# Is there a way to replace indexes in lists with another?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to use some for loops to take a sentence and capitalize the first letter of each word.

```
p1 = "the cat in the hat"

def title_creator(p1):
    p = p1.split()
    p_len = len(p)
    d = []
    for i in range(p_len):
        first_letter = p[i][0]
        m = first_letter.upper()
        d.append(m)
        p[i][0] == d[i]
    p = " ".join(p)
    return p

z = title_creator(p1)
print(z)
```

This outputs the same original sentence from the top. How would I be able to replace an index from one list to another?

-ps I'm sorry if this problem is really easy and I'm just overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is used for comparisons, while `=` is used for assignments. Additionally, strings are immutable in Python, meaning their values cannot be changed once they are created. So `p[i][0] = d[i]` should not work. Your options are as follows: convert each string to a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string)  or create a new string as seen below:

```
p1 = "the cat in the hat"

def title_creator(p1):
    p = p1.split()
    p_len = len(p)
    for i in range(p_len):
        p[i] = p[i][0].upper() + p[i][1:]
    p = " ".join(p)
    return p

z = title_creator(p1)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
The Cat In The Hat
```

Answer (score 5):

Use title():

```
p1 = "the cat in the hat"

print(p1.title())
# The Cat In The Hat
```

EDIT:

Just incase you want to experiment with for loop you can use it like this:

```
p1 = "the cat in the hat"

def title_creator(p1):
    p = p1.split()
    for index, element in enumerate(p):
        p[index] = element.capitalize()
    result = " ".join(p)
    return result

z = title_creator(p1)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost, the problem with your original code is that you are never actually updated `p` (since `==` checks the two values are equivalent, you need single equals `=` to set the left to the right). Something like this would work:

```
def title_creator(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    output = []
    for word in words:
        capitalised_word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
        output.append(capitalised_word)

    return " ".join(output)

p1 = "the cat in the hat"
z = title_creator(p1)
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

*See [SequenceToSequence's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037185/4518341) for an explanation of why your code doesn't work and [Neeraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037148/4518341) for the best practical way to do what you want (BTW, you might want to read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)). I want to answer the question at face-value.*

Yes, you can replace indexes, but it's not necessary when you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression) instead:

```
def title_creator(string):
    words = string.split()
    return ' '.join(w[0].upper()+w[1:] for w in words)

print(title_creator('the cat in the hat'))  # -> The Cat In The Hat
```