# Replace a specific character from string

Tags: python

I know how to replace characters, but I would like to have the instance done once. My code replace's all the characters before.

```
string = "Forever9999"

string = string[:-4] + string[-4:].replace("9", "1")
```

Which in the end would be Forever1999, but I get Forever1111

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `string = string[:-4] + string[-4:-3].replace("9", "1") + string[-3:]`  - you are substitution the whole remainder of the string using `string[-4:]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I was getting hopeless.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can pass another paramter to [`str.replace(old, new[, count])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), which is the max count of occurrences you want to replace:

```
string.replace("9", "1", 1)
# 'Forever1999'
```