# how to save a variable in a if statement in a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to program hangman and I run into a problem. In line 48 you see that I'm trying to copy the word that has been guessed so far. But the problem is when the program asks for the next letter. For example, if the user have guessed the letter 'h', it says `h____` and the next turn I guess the letter e it says `_e___` but I want it to say in this example `he___`.

```
word = 'hello'
guessed = False
guess_word = secret_word(word)
a = '____'

while guessed == False:
    letter = ask_letter_from_user()

    if is_the_letter_in_the_word(word, letter):
        locatie_letter_in_woord = location_of_letter_in_word(word, letter)
        a = replace(guess_word, locatie_letter_in_woord, letter)
        print(a)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call `replace(guess_word, locatie_letter_in_woord, letter)` repeatedly for each letter the user has already guessed, instead of only the letter that the user has *just* guessed?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1228299/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `a` and `guess_word` should actually be one variable.

You are passing `guess_word` to the `replace` function after every guessed letter, but you are never updating its value. Instead, you're updating `a`.

Get rid of `a`. Next time, give *all* your variables meaningful names, then you might realized that you have two variables for one purpose :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `replace(guess_word, locatie_letter_in_woord, letter)`, simply do `a = a[:locatie_letter_in_woord] + letter + a[locatie_letter_in_woord+1:]`. This will prevent the previous letter from being overwritten.

Output:

```
wich letter do you want to try?: h
well done! you guessed the letter
youre guessed letters are: h
a: h___
wich letter do you want to try?: e
well done! you guessed the letter
youre guessed letters are: h,e
a: he__
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

you can turn the word into a list and have each letter checked one by one

```
word = 'hello'
guessed = False
found = []
guess_word = secret_word(word)

while guessed == False:
    guess= ask_letter_from_user()

    if is_the_letter_in_the_word(word, letter):
        print('well done! you guessed the letter')
        word_as_list = list(guess_word)
        indices = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]
        for index in indices:
            word_as_list[index] = letter
            found.append(letter)
        print('youre guessed letters are: ' + list_joining(found))

        guess_word = "".join(word_as_list)
        print(guess_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 47 in place of:

```
a = replace(guess_word, locatie_letter_in_woord, letter)
```

write

```
a = replace(a, locatie_letter_in_woord, letter)
```

```
wich letter do you want to try?: h
well done! you guessed the letter
youre guessed letters are: h
h___
wich letter do you want to try?: e
well done! you guessed the letter
youre guessed letters are: h,e
he__
wich letter do you want to try?:
```

Still, this program has a problem. When you are calling the function:

```
def location_of_letter_in_word(word, letter):
    return word.find(letter)
```

Look carefully for the second `l` in `hello`; it will return the location of the first `l`.