# Replacing a character in a string using index - Python

Tags: python

For example I have a string:

```
word = '__________'
```

And I wanted to change the character e to I using replace but not by the letter but using index position of e which is 5

```
new = word.replace(n[5], 'i')
print(new)
```

Which won't work and give me an output like this

```
>>>iiiiiiiiii
```

Is there any way to replace a string using the index position?

Comment: it seems that you misplaced `word` with `n`?

Comment: This might help you https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/replace.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing one character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-one-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `n`  with `word`:

```py
word = 'coordenate'
new = word.replace(word[5], 'i')
print(new)
```

Output:

```sh
>>>coordinati
```

or you want to change the value by index:

```py
word = '__________'
tmp = list(word)
tmp[5] = 'i'
new = ''.join(tmp)
print(new)
```

Out put:

```sh
_____i____
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def replace_by_index(string, idx, character):
    return string[:idx] + character + string[idx+1:]
```

be careful to use only valid indexes, otherwise the character will be appended to the end of the word (or to the beginning if large negative values are used).

Answer (score 0):

A string is an immutable object, which means that you cannot *directly* change a letter into a string through its index.

In your example, you have ask to replace **all occurences** of the 6th letter, hence the result.

To change a specific letter I can imagine 2 ways:

1. use slices to separate before, the letter itself and after:

   ```
    new = word[:5] + 'i' + word[6:]
   ```
2. convert the string to a mutable sequence type like `list`

   ```
    data = list(word)
    data[5] = 'i'
    new = ''.join(data)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
word = "coordenate"
new = word.replace(word[5],'i',1)
print(new)
```

Output is :

```
coordinate
```