# Find out how i can improve my Hangman coding on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTJMo.png)i want to find out how

1. i can  take in user’s inputs on the number of times user wishes to run/play, and execute accordingly. and also how can i provide user with an option on the game/run mode
2. allow the user to choose the complexity level of a game?
3. include a scoreboard that shows the top 5 players/scores.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFwvE.png)imgur.com/CcJOM.png)

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

import random
NUMBER_OF_PICKS = 3
MINIMUM_SELECTION = 1
MAXIMUM_SELECTION = 36


#Input for the word by game master
user = input("Please enter your name:")
print("Hi " + user + " good luck ")
no_of_time = input("How many times do you want to play: ")

answer_word = list(str.lower(input("input enter your word: "))) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/change-one-character-in-a-string
clear_output()
win = False

#defining function

def guesscheck(guess,answer,guess_no):
    clear_output()
    if len(guess)==1:
        if guess in answer:
            print("Correct, ",guess," is a right letter")
            return True
        else:
            print("Incorrect, ",guess, " is a not a correct letter. That was your chance number ",guess_no)
            return False
    else:
        print("Enter only one letter")     

#Storing the number of characters in different variable
answer_display=[]
for each in answer_word:
        answer_display += ["*"]
print(answer_display)
   
#initializing number of allowable guesses
guess_no = 1   
while guess_no<5:
    clear_output
    
    #Player input for guess letter
    guess_letter=str.lower(input('Enter your guess letter: '))
    
    #Calling a sub function to check if correct letter was guessed
    guess_check=guesscheck(guess_letter,answer_word,guess_no);
    
    #Conditional: if incorrect letter
    if guess_check == False:
        guess_no +=1
        print(answer_display)
    #Conditional: if correct letter    
    elif guess_check == True:
        num = [i for i, x in enumerate(answer_word) if x == guess_letter] #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list
        for all in num:
            answer_display[all]=guess_letter
        print(answer_display)
     
    #Conditional: if no remaining unknown letter then win screen    
    if answer_display.count('*')==0:
        win = True
        break

if win:
    print("You won!")
else:
        print("The correct answer was: ", answer_word)
        print("You lost!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `random_words` package in jupyter notebook.

run this command in code shell.
`!pip install random_word`

import package. `from random_word import RandomWords`

generate.

```
r = RandomWords()
print(r.get_random_word())
```

**Code snippet:**

```
import random
from random_word import RandomWords

# Input for the word by game master
user = input("Please enter your name:")
print("Hi " + user + " good luck ")

while True:
    try:
        no_of_time = int(input("How many times do you want to play: "))
        played_time = no_of_time
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number. specify in number how many time you want to play.")


r=RandomWords()
scorecard = 0


# defining function
def guesscheck(guess, answer, guess_no):
    if len(guess) == 1:
        if guess in answer:
            print("Correct, ", guess, " is a right letter")
            return True
        else:
            print("Incorrect, ", guess, " is a not a correct letter. That was your chance number ", guess_no)
            return False
    else:
        print("Enter only one letter")

while no_of_time:

    while True:
        try:
            difficulty_level = int(input(
                "Enter the difficulty you want to play: press [1] for easy, press [2] for medium, press [3] for hard, press [4] for manually word"))
            if difficulty_level in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter number 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 not other than that!!")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter difficulty level specific.")

    answer_word = ""
    if difficulty_level == 1:
        while len(answer_word)!=5:
            answer_word = r.get_random_word()
    elif difficulty_level == 2:
        while len(answer_word)!=6:
            answer_word = r.get_random_word()
    elif difficulty_level == 3:
        while len(answer_word)!=10:
            answer_word = r.get_random_word()
    else:
        answer_word=input("Enter manually what word you wanted to set..!")

    win = False
    # Storing the number of characters in different variable
    answer_display = []
    for each in answer_word:
        answer_display += ["*"]
    print(answer_display)

    # initializing number of allowable guesses
    guess_no = 1
    while guess_no <= 5:  # User chances given 5

        # Player input for guess letter
        guess_letter = str.lower(input('Enter your guess letter: '))

        # Calling a sub function to check if correct letter was guessed
        guess_check = guesscheck(guess_letter, answer_word, guess_no)

        # Conditional: if incorrect letter
        if guess_check == False:
            guess_no += 1
            print(answer_display)
        # Conditional: if correct letter
        elif guess_check == True:
            num = [i for i, x in enumerate(answer_word) if
                   x == guess_letter]  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list
            for all in num:
                answer_display[all] = guess_letter
            print(answer_display)

        # Conditional: if no remaining unknown letter then win screen
        if answer_display.count('*') == 0:
            win = True
            break

    if win:
        print("You won!")
        scorecard += 1
    else:
        print("The correct answer was: ", answer_word)
        print("You lost!")

    no_of_time -= 1

print("You played " + str(played_time) + ":")
print("Won: " + str(scorecard) + " Guessed correctly!!")
print("Lose: " + str(played_time - scorecard) + "not Guessed correctly!!")
```

don't know why specific length is not working in `random_word` hence included `while` statement.. this code snippet is working you can go through this..!