# using ctypes.memset() in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, memset

I am trying to memset a substring in python file using ctypes.memset

Here is the code I am using:

```
import ctypes

def memz(string):
    buffsize = len(string)+1
    size = sys.getsizeof(string)
    offset = size - buffsize
    start = string.find('{') -----------> 142
    end = string.find('}') + 1  --------> 167
    location = id(string)
    ctypes.memset(location + offset + start, 0, end-start)
```

I see that this does not memset the substring, but writes some other part of memory. I suspect I am not passing the correct memory location to ctypes.memset.
Do I need to change the format of the location(location + offset + start) that I am passing to ctypes.memset?

PS: The solution is derived from [Mark data as sensitive in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982682/mark-data-as-sensitive-in-python/49458190#49458190). I tried that solution but using the memset from  ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').memset results in a seg fault. I am using Python2.7.11.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works too. I tried running it locally and it cleared the required substring.

```
str = 'This is a {sample} string'

print(ctypes.string_at(id(str), sys.getsizeof(str)))

buffSize = len(str)+1
size = sys.getsizeof(str)
offset = size - buffSize
start = str.find('{')
end = str.find('}') + 1
location = id(str)

ctypes.memset(location + offset + start, 0, end-start)

print(ctypes.string_at(id(str), sys.getsizeof(str)))
```

It produces following output

```
 ���A,�5~��dThis is a {sample} string
 ���A,�5~��dThis is a  string
```

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. I tried it in my local machine too and it worked, but it does not work as part of a big code where i am using it.

Comment: Probably you can try different way to calculate the offset from the starting location.
you may want to use the 

`startIndex = ctypes.string_at(id(string), sys.getsizeof(string)).find('{') 
endIndex = ctypes.string_at(id(string), sys.getsizeof(string)).find('}')`

and then use memset

`memset( id(string) + startIndex, 0, endIndex-startIndex+1)`