# Python del to mark an secure instance variable garbage collected

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have a sensitive data field that I want to have as shortest life cycle as possible in memory. Following the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728164/securely-erasing-password-in-memory-python) I have the following implementation:

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(data):
        self.user_data = data #sensitive data 

    def get_user_data(self):
        return UserData.decrypt(self.user_data)

    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(data):
        ...
```

Following the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728164/securely-erasing-password-in-memory-python), it seems the best I can do is to use del and make the string available for GC. I have the following implementation:

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(data):
        self.user_data = data #sensitive data 
        self._decrypted_user_data = None 

    @contextmanager      
    def get_user_data(self):
        self._decrypted_user_data = UserData.decrypt(self.user_data)
        yield
        del self._decrypted_user_data

    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(data):
        ...
```

I have two questions:

Does the del on instance variable make the variable available for GC (i.e. is the reference count 0 on the instance variable). The reason I am asking is because I know **dict** returns the attributes. If not is there a way to mark the instance ready for GC instead of the whole object?

Is it safer than doing self._decrypted_user_data = None?

Comment: What is the reasoning for making the data a property of the object, and having a del after yield?

Answer (score 3):

`del` marks an object as garbage, but doesn't zap it.

In Python, strings are immutable. Even if you `del` a string, it'll exist in memory, although unretrievable.  Considering using another type that *is* overwritable:

> **bytearray([source[, encoding[, errors]]])**
>
> Return a new array of bytes.
>   The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <=
>   x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences,
>   described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as most methods that the
>   bytes type has, see Bytes and Byte Array Methods.

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray

To store a password, read/write it as a `bytearray`, ie a string of numbers. To delete the password, overwrite the elements of the `bytearray`, then `del` the reference. Even if the object were to resurface, it would be filled with gibberish.

Comment: Thanks! The caller expects the password to be a string to pass into some web service call. I guess the caller could convert from byteaaray to string but then I will have the same problem.

Comment: To be honest I'd just use a string and `del` it, but the `bytearray` method seems like it would make paranoid security types happier.