# Clearing (zeroing) all bytes of a sensitive bytearray in memory

Tags: python, python-bytearray

After reading the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51936887/4494781), I want to make sure a `bytearray` with sensitive information (password) is correctly cleared in memory prior to garbage collection. I'm assuming garbage collection in python only removes the pointer but does not replace the actual data with zeros in memory.

What is the correct way of doing this?

This is what I'm trying to do, but I don't know how to verify that it works as intended:

```
class CachedPasswordWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """A base class for widgets that may prompt the user for a  password and
    remember that password for the lifetime of that widget.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        parent: Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # store the password as a mutable type so the memory can be zeroed after it is no longer needed
        self._pwd: Optional[bytearray] = None

    @property
    def pwd(self) -> Optional[str]:
        """Return password.

        Open a dialog to ask for the wallet password if necessary, and cache it.
        If the password dialog is cancelled, return None.
        """
        if self._pwd is not None:
            return self._pwd.decode("utf-8")

        # password = PasswordDialog(parent=self).run()
        password = getpass.getpass()
        if password is None:
            # dialog cancelled
            return
                
        self._pwd = bytearray(password.encode("utf-8"))
        return self._pwd.decode("utf-8")

    def __del__(self):
        if self._pwd is not None:
            self._pwd[:] = b"\0" * len(self._pwd)
```

I guess what I'm asking is whether I can be sure that overwriting a slice of a bytearray will overwrite exactly the same memory as was used before, and whether I can be sure `__del__` will be called in a timely manner by the garbage collector.

Comment: You can be sure, also `__del__` is not called by the garbage collector, this is not java, `__del__` is called at the exact point in time when there are 0 references to the object, after the operation that decrements the refcount happens.

Comment: The `__del__` method is called when the object is about to be destroyed by the garbage collector. However, relying on `__del__` for resource management is not advisable because the timing of garbage collection is not deterministic. 

Consider using `contextlib.closing` or a context manager to ensure resources are managed deterministically.

Comment: The interaction with QT is the only thing to be concerned about, QT delays any deletion of widgets to not cause segfault, so i am guessing you should manually delete it instead of relying on QT to delete it, maybe in some "OnClose" signal.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I'd say both are unsure, implementation details. Pypy I think doesn't use reference counts, and the slice assignment doesn't have to copy, *could* just change the array's pointer and free the old one.